# Has Canada started allowing TRV Applications for Visit Visas?

Tags: visas, canada, nigerian-citizens

I got refused for Canadian visas around 2019, grounds I had no travel history. So recently I have visited some countries and I have come back home. Is this the right time to apply? I have visited 2 East African nations (Rwanda and Ethiopia) and some West African nations as well, was thinking of Visiting the UAE any time sooner.

I am from Nigeria.

Comment: You must have a very good reason to come right now, such as close family or to provide an essential service. (see https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/coronavirus-covid19/travel-restrictions-exemptions.html#foreign ). If you just want to visit you will not be admitted, even though applications are allowed. What is your reason for visiting?

Comment: @KateGregory, basically visit / Vacation. And then get to see my cousin in Ontario.

Comment: You are not going to be admitted for a vacation until Covid restrictions are done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears that the applications are now open. One of my friends did apply last week and he was told that if he did miss it this time, it's until 2023, so good luck!

Comment: thanks for the information. I will submit immediately. As a nigerian, do you think travel history to several West african nations and 2 East african nations is worth it?

Comment: @Quinn It’s better than nothing, however nowhere near as strong as travel to equivalent jurisdictions such as Schengen. Was lack of travel history the only reason for the refusal? Can you convince Canadian Immigration that you have ties—such as a job, home, financial assets or family—that will take you back to your home country?

Comment: @Traveller, Thanks for the heads up.
I have a Job, I work in a Bank, My salary is #6.4million naira / annually.
I have an Estate (Handed over to me by my father), I am not yet Married, then these history. What do you think?

Comment: @Quinn If you had similar ties when you were refused, it could go either way. If I were you I’d wait until after the UAE visit.

Comment: @Traveller, Which is even Wiser. I think thats what I will do.